# How to change the state of an array of children components inside a parent using Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks

I have parent component which has a div that contains a ol with custom components inside.
Each of those components has a state where I store a 'checked' boolean. I need a button in my parent component that will clear ALL of the child components state and set it to false. I'm attempting to use 'useRef' and 'useImperativeHandle' but can't figure it out.

**CountryListing (child component)**

```
export default function CountryListing({ country }, ref) {
const countryRef = useRef();
const [checkbox, toggleCheckbox] = useState(false)

const clearCheckbox = () => {
    toggleCheckbox(false);
}

 useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
     clear: () => {ref.current.clearCheckbox()}
    }
));

return (
    <li key={country}  >
        <div className="country-listing-container">
            <input type="checkbox" className="country-checkbox" id={country + "Checkbox"} ref={countryRef} value={checkbox} onChange={() => toggleCheckbox(!checkbox)}></input>
            <img src={'https://storage.googleapis.com/flags-bucket/flags/' + getImageFor(country)} className="country-flag" alt={country + "'s flag icon."}></img>
            <p className="country-name"> {country} </p>
        </div>
    </li>
);
```

}

**Collapsible (parent component)**

```
export default function Collapsible() {
  const [open, togglePanel] = useState(false);
  const [countries] = useState(["Mexico", "Brazil", "United Kingdom", "Not Provided - Canada", "United States", "Russia", "Australia", "Peru", "China", "Taiwan", "Pakistan", "Yemen", "Thailand", "New Zealand", "Czech Republic", "Spain", "Japan", "South Korea", "South Africa", "Argentina", "Afghanistan", "Angola", "Andorra", "Armenia", "Fiji", "Finland", "Estonia", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "Hungary", "Iran", "Ireland", "Austria", "Poland", "Kuwait", "Libya", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Mozambique", "Nepal", "Italy", "Norway", "Barbados", "Bolivia", "Bulgaria", "Chile", "Colombia"]);

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState(countries);

  //TODO title is not showing completely
  const [title] = "Locations";
  const ref = useRef(false);

  const countryComponents = (countries) => {
    const countriesList = countries.map(thisCountry => <CountryListing country={thisCountry} ref={ref} />);
    return countriesList;
  }

  const [countryComponentsList, modifyCountryComponentsList] = useState(countryComponents(searchResults))
  const clearAllAction = () => {
    ref.current.clearCheckbox();
  }


  const Initials = (countries) => {
    const [countryInitials] = useState(getInitials(countries.countries));
    const listInitials = countryInitials.map((initial) => <li key={initial}> {initial} </li>);

    return (
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>{listInitials}</ul>
    )
  }

  const search = (term) => {
    console.log('searchTerm is ' + searchTerm);
    if (!term) {
      setSearchResults(countries);
    }
    else {
      const results = countries.filter(country => country.toLowerCase().includes(term));
      setSearchResults(results);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="top-header">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Filter Locations" value={searchTerm}
          onKeyUp={(event) => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
            search(searchTerm);
          }}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
            search(searchTerm);
          }}
          onLoad={(event) => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
            search(searchTerm);
          }}
        >
        </input>
        <button onClick={() => search(searchTerm)}> S </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div onClick={() => togglePanel(!open)} className="header">
          {title}
        </div>
        {
          open ? (
            <>
              <div className="before-content"><button id="clearAllButton" onClick={clearAllAction()} > X Clear All </button></div>
              <div className="content">
                <div className="basic-grid">
                  <div className="card">

                    <ol style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
                      {countryComponentsList}
                    </ol>
                  </div>

                  <div className="card">
                    <Initials countries={countries} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          ) : null
        }
      </div >
    </>
  );
}
```

I've tried searching for an answer but nothing helps me understand it and they usually mention single components. Although my understanding is that I need to implement it for one component and then map them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have that much familiarity with the way you are trying to do it, but I can suggest an alternative. Instead of doing that, you can do something like this:

```
const [checkedElements, setCheckedElements] = useState([]);
```

Then when you map and create the elements you can use the index of the map method to say something like

```
onClick={()=>setCheckedElements([...checkedElements, index])}
checked={checkedElements.includes(index)}
```

You can clear all the elements when clicking the button by adding this on the button:

```
onClick={setCheckedElements([])}
```

Comment: I was actually thinking of trying something similar to this. I will try it and update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

this is a full working example, you can check all label from parent:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, label: "Wake up", completed: true },
    { id: 2, label: "Make Coffee", completed: false },
    { id: 3, label: "Go to Work", completed: false }
  ]);
  const checkAll = React.useMemo(() => {
    const filterTodos = Object.assign([], todos);
    return (
      filterTodos.filter(f => f.completed === true).length === todos.length
    );
  }, [todos]);
  const checkAllTodos = e => {
    const value = e.target.checked;
    setTodos(current => current.map(f => ({ ...f, completed: value })));
  };
  const checkTodo = React.useCallback(id => {
    setTodos(current =>
      current.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) return { ...item, completed: !item.completed };
        else return item;
      })
    );
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={checkAll} onChange={checkAllTodos} />
          todos {checkAll}
        </li>
        {todos.map(item => (
          <Todo
            id={item.id}
            checked={item.completed}
            key={item.id}
            change={checkTodo}
          >
            {item.label}
          </Todo>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
const Todo = React.memo(({ checked, children, id, change }) => (
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={() => change(id)} />
    {children}
  </li>
));
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```